# Ethernet 1000Base-T Inter Packet Gap measurements

Tags: ethernet

Is it possible to measure the length interpacket gap of a 1000Base-T signal with an oscilloscope without PAM5 decoding? I want to measure the length of the interpacket gap for a specific device.

In my setup I split the 8 data pairs into individual coaxial cables and use a directional coupler to get the signal from a single direction. I can see the PAM5 traffic, however I'm not sure what's transmitted in the interpacket gap on the wire.

Is it possible to see 0V for a certain time, or is the interpacket gap also scrambled and PAM5 coded?
Does anyone have a oscilloscope screenshot of a interpacket gap on the wire?

BR Franz